# Using Rvest to Scrape NY Times Sudoku Puzzle

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the [NY Times sudoku puzzle](https://www.nytimes.com/puzzles/sudoku/easy), but when I use `rvest` it doesn't scrape to the level I'm looking for. However, when I'm looking through the css using the developer tools all the data seems to be there. It seems the following should work,

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.nytimes.com/puzzles/sudoku/easy"
webpage <- read_html(url)

webpage %>%
  html_node(".su-stretch")
```

which returns an empty list. Ideally I want to grab the value in each cell, but I'm not able to scrape anything below the `.pz-game-field` node. Is there something I am missing? Is there a way to scrape the puzzle?

---

For those interested why I'm doing this... My parents have ColorKu (colors instead of numbers) and are looking for more puzzles. Yes I could show them how to convert numbers to color by themselves, but that seems to be against the coding creed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the page, you'll see that the table is rendered using Javascript. The game data is stored in a variable, `window.gameData`.

So you can extract the Javascript like this:

```
js <- webpage %>% 
  html_nodes("script") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Inspection shows that `js[1]` contains the data for the game. You can transform the data into JSON:

```
js1 <- gsub("window.gameData = ", "", js[1])
```

and then convert to a list:

```
library(jsonlite)

js1 <- fromJSON(js1)
```

Then, for example, the cell values for the "easy" puzzle, as a vector:

```
js1$easy$puzzle_data$puzzle

[1] 0 0 4 1 0 0 5 2 7 2 1 3 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 6 2 4 0 0 0 3 5 0 2 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 8 7 5 0 4 0 0 0 6 0 1 3 4 7 2 0 1 0 0 5 0 0 3 1 0 6 2 0 0 9 9 0 0 0 0 0 1 8 0
```

You could represent the grid as a matrix:

```
matrix(js1$easy$puzzle_data$puzzle, nrow = 9, byrow = TRUE)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    0    4    1    0    0    5    2    7
 [2,]    2    1    3    7    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    7    6    2    4    0    0    0
 [4,]    3    5    0    2    7    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    3    0    8    7    5
 [6,]    0    4    0    0    0    6    0    1    3
 [7,]    4    7    2    0    1    0    0    5    0
 [8,]    0    3    1    0    6    2    0    0    9
 [9,]    9    0    0    0    0    0    1    8    0
```

Warning - hints and the solution are stored in the data too!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(The solution from @neilfws is better but including in case useful to someone.)

Here's a kludgier approach that extracts the three puzzle levels as strings:

```
library(tidyverse)
webpage %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = "puzzle") %>%
  slice(4,7,10) %>%
  mutate(last_char = str_locate(value, "\\]")[1]) %>%
  mutate(code = str_sub(value, 6, last_char - 1)) %>%
  pull(code)

[1] "0,4,1,0,0,5,2,7,2,1,3,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,6,2,4,0,0,0,3,5,0,2,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,8,7,5,0,4,0,0,0,6,0,1,3,4,7,2,0,1,0,0,5,0,0,3,1,0,6,2,0,0,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,1,8,0"
[2] "6,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,8,0,0,9,3,1,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,4,0,0,7,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,9,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,3,1,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0"
[3] "0,0,9,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,2,0,0,3,9,0,5,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,4,6,0,0,0,8,9,0,0,7,0,1,0,5,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,7,3,9,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
```